# My code is fine but have issue because of android emulator

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My read file from chanel, the code was working fine but after adding more functionality in app it

```
 05-11 09:23:53.339: E/ThrottleService(300): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 05-11 09:24:05.699: D/dalvikvm(300): GC_CONCURRENT freed 584K, 63% free 4903K/13000K, paused 99ms+56ms, total 569ms
```

I have search for this problem but get not enough information to solve this. I have this problem in following code. I am running this code in asyntask

```
public class screencahnge extends AsyncTask < String, Bitmap, Bitmap > {
    ImageView im2 = null;
    Bitmap b = null;
    int ch = 0;

    boolean flag = true;
    public screencahnge(ImageView im) {

        im2 = im;

    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub'
        // Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if (RemoteScreen.out == null) {
            System.out.print("Its null dude");
        }
        try {
            RemoteScreen.out.write(210);
            //Home.threadloop = false;  
            b = fileReceived(RemoteScreen. in );
            publishProgress(b);
            b = null;
            ch = 4646;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap...images) {

        if (images[0] != null)
            im2.setImageBitmap(images[0]);
        images = null;
        b.recycle();

        doInBackground("");
        System.gc();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        b.recycle();

    }

    public Bitmap fileReceived(InputStream is)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "a.png";
        String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
        System.out.println(imageInSD);
        if (is != null) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                // Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");
                //ContextWrapper context = null;
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) > 0) {
                    if (bytesRead == 1)
                        break;
                    bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                    System.out.println("Loop" + aByte);

                }

                bos.close();

                System.out.println("Loop out");
                java.io.FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageInSD);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( in );
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);

                Log.i("IMSERVICE", "saved");
                if (bitmap != null)
                    System.out.println(bitmap.toString());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling      
                //      Log.i("IMSERVICE", "exception ");
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }


}
```

This code read image from channel and set to imageview, this code worked fine for me before but now I am using this code in this app having this problem.I have tried many solution. I created new emulator and test on that emulator. I checked all required permissions. I added internet permissions, networkstate permissions etc.

Thanks in advance